# How to get OpenCV and ArUco Working with Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv, aruco

How can I add ArUco to my XCode project?

I installed the OpenCV framework version 3.3.0 and 3.4.0 but I didn't find ArUco's files

Comment: You need to install opencv_contrib along with opencv to get aruco installed

Comment: i tried but i got like this issue [https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6093]